# User can't edit his question

Tags: support, edits

In this question

[Bug in rendering paper-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720197)

the indentation of the last code line was one character short and therefore the line wasn't shown.

The comment of the user indicates, that he tried to fix the formatting but was not able to edit his question.

Is there anything obvious why he wouldn't be allowed to edit his question?

Comment: This means there is no obvious reason? That's what I suspected. I just wanted to be sure before I try to teach the user.

Answer (score 3):

It usually means the user doesn't *know* how to edit the question. Unless it is a deleted question or the post is locked, the OP can **always** edit their post. That post fits none of those criteria.

The only other issue I can think of is a local network appliance (firewall, router) filtering HTTP POSTs in a misplaced attempt to prevent injection attacks; especially when SQL statements are involved.

There *are* quality filters in place that will prevent certain edits from being made by lower-rep users; I don't see any reason why that might apply here though.

Without any further feedback from the user, it is impossible to tell which one applies here.

Comment: As an aside: *creating* a question needs HTTP POST to be enabled too. (Maybe editing uses PUT in JavaScript, but the plain edit `<form>` uses POST too, and if POST is filtered, then so is PUT, probably.)

Comment: It is specific keywords that routers filter on, not necessarily all POSTs.